# How to remove a `tag listener` in Phonegap NFC plugin

Tags: cordova, callback, phonegap-plugins, nfc

I am using chariotsolution's nfc plugin for phonegap (https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) and it's all working perfect until the time came that I needed to **remove a listener**. I can't do it and it seems like it's not working.

My question is, is this a common bug? Has anyone ever tried to remove a listener and succeeded? If so how did you do it?

I used `addTagDiscoveredListener` and `removeTagDiscoveredListener`.

**Code for adding listener**

```
    var win = function() {
        showMessage({method:'alert',type:'warning',message:"Listening for NFC tags"});
        spinner.hide();
    }

    var fail = function() {
        swal("Fail", 'Failed to register NFC Listener', "error");
    }

    nfcevt = nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(writeTag, win, fail);
```

**Code for removing listener**

```
nfc.removeTagDiscoveredListener(function() {
  console.log('callback here');
}, 
function() {
  console.log('success: removed');
}, 
function() {
  console.log('fail: not removed');
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Michael Roland's answer, I got a better understanding of how it works so I constructed a function to manage my NdefListener callbacks.

```
var currentListenerCallback; //global, this one is.

function replaceCurrentNdefListener(newCallback) {
    nfc.removeNdefListener(
        currentListenerCallback, 
        function() {
            console.log('successfully removed listener callback: writeTag()');

            currentListenerCallback = newCallback; //make the new callback the current callback

            nfc.addNdefListener (
                currentListenerCallback,
                nfcwin, nfcfail);
        }, 
        function() {
            console.log("error: " + "unable to remove listener callback");   
        });
}

function nfcwin() {
   console.log("Success. Waiting for NFC Tag...")
}
function nfcfail(error) {
   console.log("Error adding NDEF Listener " + JSON.stringify(error))
}
```

So basically, I created a global variable that will hold the current callback for the tag listener. The function will then receive the replacement callback and automatically remove the `currentListenerCallback` and put the `newCallback` as the new `currentListenerCallback`. The function then adds a new NdefListener using the new `currentListenerCallback`.

**Hope this helps someone in the future. Happy coding!**

Comment: How do you call "currentListenerCallback" ?

Comment: @Sunny_Sid it is being called as a callback in addNdefListener: `nfc.addNdefListener (
                currentListenerCallback,
                nfcwin, nfcfail);`

Comment: Great, It helped me (y)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `removeTagDiscoveredListener()` to remove the callback function that you previously registered with `addTagDiscoveredListener()` So if you have,

```
nfcevt = nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(writeTag, win, fail);
```

then `writeTag` must be the callback function that you registered, so you would use this to remove it again:

```
nfc.removeTagDiscoveredListener(writeTag,
                                function() { console.log('success: removed'); },
                                function() { console.log('fail: not removed'); });
```

Trying to remove an inline function that has not been registered before makes no sense.

---

Even if `removeTagDiscoveredListener()` is called for an invalid callback (event listener), phonegap-nfc.js calls code that supposedly should stop the event from being triggered (eventhough the initially registered callback remains registered for the event listener itself). However, at least on Android, the plugin **always** registers for the `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent, which in turn leads to the tag discovered listener to be fired. This is done regardless of registered event listeners. However, there is (currently unused and not accessible from JavaScript layer) code that suggests that this behavior may change in future.

Comment: Ok, to make it clear for me: removeTagDiscoveredListener removes the callback and not the listener?

Comment: @clintgh True, there seems to be code that supposedly should stop the event from being triggered even if `removeTagDiscoveredListener` is called for an invalid callback (and therefore would not remove the callback listener itself). However, at least on Android, this does not seem to be used. See edit.

Comment: It all makes sense now, I guess we'll just have to wait til they fully develop that functionality. For now, I will test what you suggested and see if it works

Comment: it worked. Thanks, I will update my question and put a function that I constructed to properly manage the listener callbacks, to help others.

Comment: @clintgh You may want to provide that as your own answer instead of an edit to your question, though.